# CRITICAL:NutterCLI:403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://adb-2xxxxxxxxxxxx7.1x.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/workspace/list?path=

Tags: azure-devops, databricks, azure-databricks

I have the below yml build definition file to deploy the test notebooks to the Azure Databricks workspace and run the smoke tests using microsoft's "nutter" test framework for Databricks, but the **'Execute Smoke Tests'** script step fails with the following error:

**CRITICAL:NutterCLI:403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://adb-2xxxxxxxxxxxx7.1x.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/workspace/list?path=**

Note: When I run the same steps from within the "Release" pipeline in Azure Devops the command executes successfully, this confirms that the "DATABRICKS_TOKEN" used is valid.

yml build definition file:

```
    stages:
  - stage: ${{ parameters.stageName }}
    dependsOn: ${{ parameters.stageDependsOn }}
    displayName: ${{ parameters.stageDisplayName }}
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ parameters.condition }}', 'trigger'))
    variables:
      - group: ${{ parameters.variableGroup }}
    jobs:
      - deployment: Deploy
        displayName: Deploy job
        pool:
          vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
        environment: ${{ parameters.adoEnvironment }}
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
                  inputs:
                    buildType: "current"
                    downloadType: "single"
                    artifactName: "drop"
                    downloadPath: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"

                - task: UsePythonVersion@0
                  inputs:
                    versionSpec: 3.5
                    addToPath: true
                    architecture: "x64"

                - task: AzureCLI@2
                  inputs:
                    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.azureSubscription }}
                    scriptType: bash
                    scriptPath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/drop/Deployment/fetch_databricks_url_token.sh
                  env:
                    DATABRICKS_WORKSPACE: $(databricksName)
                    RESOURCE_GROUP: $(resourceGroupName)
                  displayName: Get Databricks PAT Token

                - task: configuredatabricks@0
                  inputs:
                    url: "$(DATABRICKS_HOST_URL)"
                    token: "$(DATABRICKS_TOKEN)"

                - ${{ if eq(parameters.deployNotebooks, true) }}:
                    - task: deploynotebooks@0
                      inputs:
                        notebooksFolderPath: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/drop/IntegrationTests"
                        workspaceFolder: "/Shared/TestPlan/Deployment/IntegrationTests"

                - script: 'pip install nutter'
                  displayName: 'Install Nutter'

                - script: |
                    nutter run /Shared/TestPlan/Deployment/IntegrationTests/SmokeTests/Tests/ $CLUSTER --recursive --junit_report --timeout 5400 --max_parallel_tests 3
                  displayName: 'Execute Smoke Tests'
                  env:
                    CLUSTER: ${{parameters.clusterId}}
                    DATABRICKS_HOST: $(DATABRICKS_HOST_URL)
                    DATABRICKS_TOKEN: $(DATABRICKS_TOKEN)

                - task: PublishTestResults@2
                  displayName: 'Publish Smoke Test Results **/test-*.xml'
                  inputs:
                    testResultsFiles: '**/test-*.xml'
                    testRunTitle: 'Smoke Test Run'
                  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

fetch_databricks_url_token.sh --> Script used to generate "DATABRICKS_TOKEN"

```sh
# Get a token for the global Databricks application.
# The resource name is fixed and never changes.
token_response=$(az account get-access-token --resource 2xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-cxxxxxx)
token=$(jq .accessToken -r <<< "$token_response")
# Get a token for the Azure management API
token_response=$(az account get-access-token --resource https://management.core.windows.net/)
azToken=$(jq .accessToken -r <<< "$token_response")
# You can also generate a PAT token. Note the quota limit of 600 tokens.
api_response=$(curl -sf $DATABRICKS_HOST_URL/api/2.0/token/create \
 -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" \
 -H "X-Databricks-Azure-SP-Management-Token:$azToken" \
 -H "X-Databricks-Azure-Workspace-Resource-Id:$wsId" \
 -d '{ "lifetime_seconds": 1800, "comment": "Pipeline Temp Token" }')
# Set ENV Variables DATABRICKS_TOKEN for later steps
echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=DATABRICKS_TOKEN]' $(jq .token_value -r <<< "$api_response")
```

Comment: is `DATABRICKS_TOKEN` defined as sensitive variable?

Comment: @AlexOtt I've just edited the original Question to include the script that i used to generate the `DATABRICKS_TOKEN`. I'm not very sure if this variable assignment is considered sensitive or not. Kindly let me know if you need any additional details.

Comment: no. that isn't sensitive. I was asking about variables defined in the Library or on the pipeline level.